# Windows service needs too long to start, timeout reached

Tags: windows, visual-c++, service, windows-services

I have created one service with following build env:

`OS : Windows Server 2012
 IDE: Visual Studio 2012
 Arch: x64`

Same service is working fine with Windows Server 2012 but The same service is not starting in Windows Server 2008.

`OS : Windows Server 2008 R2
Arch : x64`

I am getting following error in Event Viewer

> A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the  service to connect.

Note : I have installed all the necessary VC++ redistributable package needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your Service needs to long to start on the Windows Server 2008 machine. If the timeout is exceeded the service will be stopped. This could be due to different reasons like the following:

- slower hardware
- slower network connection
- different workload
- ...

I would recommend to create a worker `Thread` in the starting method of the service. This avoids the Timeout.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // Create working thread
    Thread serviceThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        // do stuff
    });

    // start thread
    serviceThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating another thread I have changed the ServicesPipeTimeout still I am getting error. Both platforms have 1 core & 4GB of RAM.

Comment: I think, that is pretty standard